# Find upto first two occurrences of an element from the list of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript arraylist with below elements

```
list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header2", code: ""},
 {header: "header3", code: ""},
 {header: "header4", code: ""}
]
```

how to filter the array to get first 2 occurrences of element "header"

Expected output:

```
list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header2", code: ""}
]
```

Any feasible and efficient solution to achieve this in javascript.

Comment: Why your expected output have `{label: "label1", price: 10}`

Comment: why you updated the expected output after getting a lot of answers? and your question does not match your expected answer.

Comment: @AZ_ he wants all the elements upto the second header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the array by cheking the `count` and get either non header items or decrement the count.

```js
const
    topHeaders = (array, count = 2) =>
        array.filter(({ header }) => count && (!header || count--));

console.log(topHeaders([]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { label: "label1" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { label: "label1" }, { header: "header2" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { header: "header2" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { header: "header2" }, { header: "header3" }, { header: "header4" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { header: "header2" }, { header: "header3" }, { label: "label1" }, { header: "header4" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { label: "label1" }, { header: "header2" }, { header: "header3" }, { header: "header4" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { label: "label1" }, { label: "label2" }, { header: "header2" }, { header: "header3" }, { header: "header4" }]));
console.log(topHeaders([{ header: "header1" }, { label: "label1" }, { label: "label2" }, { header: "header2" }, { header: "header3" }, { label: "label" }, { header: "header4" }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is not working when I have the list like this ```const list = [ {header: "header1", code: ""}, {header: "header2", code: ""}]```

Comment: Well, the code seems to be not generic, because its failing when I have only one header element. const list = [ {header: "header1", code: ""}]

Comment: Yeah, it's working. Can you explain me how its working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for you.

```
var j = 0;
var srch = 'header';
var newlist = [];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
    var obj = list[i];
    for(var prop in obj)
    {
        if(prop == srch)
        {
            newlist.push(obj);
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(j == 2)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

your expected output will be in newlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

1. Use `filter()` to get out all the elements with property `header`
2. Use `findIndex()` on `list` to match the required element `2` of array.
3. Use `slice()` to get the part of array from `first` header to the required header by passing the index found using `findIndex` to the `slice()`

```js
const list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header2", code: ""},
 {header: "header3", code: ""},
 {header: "header4", code: ""}
]

const getItems = (arr,num) => list.slice(0,arr.findIndex(a => a === arr.filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('header'))[num-1])+1)

console.log(getItems(list,2));
console.log(getItems([ {header: "header1", code: ""}, {header: "header2", code: ""}],2));
```

Comment: This is not working when I have the list like this ```const list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""}, {header: "header2", code: ""}]```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code.

```js
 var list = [{header: "header1", code: ""}, {label: "label1", price: 10}, {header: "header2", code: ""}, {header: "header3", code: ""}, {header: "header4", code: ""}];

     var j = 0;
     list = list.filter((ar, i) => {
  if(ar.hasOwnProperty('header') && j < 2){
  j++;       
  return ar;
     }
     });

     console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter and take the first two like below.

```js
const  list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header2", code: ""},
 {header: "header3", code: ""},
 {header: "header4", code: ""}
];

const headersArray = list.filter((item) =>
  item.header
).slice(0, 2);


console.log("The results are ", headersArray)
```

Comment: My expected output is {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header2", code: ""} not {header: "header1", code: ""},{header: "header2", code: ""}

Answer (score 0):

Here I push the object into another array one by one, while counting the object that has `header`. If the `header` counter equals to 2 then stop pushing objects.

```js
const list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header2", code: ""},
 {header: "header3", code: ""},
 {header: "header4", code: ""}
], maxHeader = 2
let result = [], headCounter = 0
list.forEach(item => {
  if (headCounter < maxHeader){
    if (item.header) headCounter++
    result.push(item)
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

using Reduce :

```
list.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {

if(accumulator.length < 2 && currentValue.hasOwnProperty('header')){
  accumulator.push(currentValue);
}
 return accumulator;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for your scenario.

```
var list = [
          {header: "header1", code: ""},
          {label: "label1", price: 10},
          {header: "header2", code: ""},
          {header: "header3", code: ""},
          {header: "header4", code: ""}
         ]
var counter = 0
var i = 0

list.map(obj => {
        if(counter >= 2){
           list.splice(i,i)
        }
        if(obj["header"]){
          counter++;
       }
    i++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0, j = list.length; i < j; i++) {
    if(count >=2){
        break
    }
    list[i]['header'] ? count++ : '';
    arr.push(list[i]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Hope it helps you !